# What's the best way to distribute a cli using deno?

Tags: command-line-interface, deno

I have a command line too written in Deno (let's call it `my-cli`).

I want users to be able to install it easily, e.g. by copy pasting a single command (let's assume they use Mac/Linux while Windows is nice to have).

After copy the command and running it the user should be able to run `my-cli` and it should run my code according to some entry point.

Notes:

- users may not have Deno itself installed
- users should be able to easily upgrade the cli, e.g. by running `my-cli upgrade`

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`deno compile` can be used to compile standalone binaries from your TS/JS entrypoint script. It essentially creates a copy of the current installed version of Deno with the bundled module graph embedded in the resulting binary. The tool is documented at [`https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/compiler`](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/compiler).

Here's the most basic example, and the documentation link above includes more details.

> ### Compiling Executables
>
> `deno compile [--output <OUT>] <SRC>` will compile the script into a self-contained executable.
>
> ```txt
> > deno compile https://deno.land/std/examples/welcome.ts
> ```
>
> If you omit the `OUT` parameter, the name of the executable file will be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

If the repo is public and on Github, you can [distribute it](https://deno.com/add_module) via the official [Deno Third Party Modules register](https://deno.land/x).

However, as Deno says, it can import modules from any location on the web, like GitHub, a personal webserver, or a CDN like esm.sh, Skypack, jspm.io or jsDelivr.

Once it's distributed, anyone can install it via the [`deno install`](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/script_installer#script-installer) command.

For example, if your public repo is at `https://github.com/your-name/my-cli`, any could run:

```bash
deno install https://github.com/your-name/my-cli
```